# Adding additional functionality to a PHP form

Tags: php, forms

Given the code below when I select a value from my dropdown box [S, M, L] and hit submit I get one of the following outputs:

```
S is equal to
M is equal to
L is equal to
```

I would like the output to be along the lines of

```
S is equal to Small 
M is equal to Medium 
L is equal to Large
```

Can something be added to my code to accomplish this? Or do I need to take a different approach?

```
<form action="?" method="post">

<?php
$size = array();
$size[] = "";
$size[] = "S";
$size[] = "M";
$size[] = "L";
if(isset($_REQUEST['list'])){

    echo $size[(int)$_REQUEST['list']]." is equal to "."<br />"; 

}

echo '<select name="list">'."\n";
$count = 0;

foreach($size as $size){
    echo '<option value="'.$count.'">'.$size.'</option>'."\n";

    $count++;
}
echo '</select>';
?>

<input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>


<form action="?" method="post">
```

Comment: @everyone, thanks for all the options and quick responses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this solution you can reuse the original static array to populate the post echo. Also try to avoid using \n in your html instead use the semantic `<br>`.

```
<form action="?" method="post">

<?php
$size = array(""=>"","Small"=>"S","Medium"=>"M","Large"=>"L");

if(isset($_REQUEST['list'])){

    echo $size[$_REQUEST['list']]." is equal to ".$_REQUEST['list']."<br />"; 

}

echo "<select name='list'>";

foreach($size as $key=>$value){
    echo "<option value='$key'>$value</option>";

}
echo '</select>';
?>

<input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: @enfield no problem quick question if you don't mind how long have you been coding in php??

Answer (score 3):

Why not use an associative array and then you don't have to mess around with ints or `$count`s?

```php
<form action="?" method="post">

  <?php
    $sizes = array(
      "S" => "Small",
      "M" => "Medium",
      "L" => "Large"
    );

    if(isset($_REQUEST['list'])){
      echo "<p>" . $_REQUEST['list'] . " is equal to " . $sizes[$_REQUEST['list']] . "</p>"; 
    }
  ?>

  <select name="list">
    <option value="">Choose one</option>
    <?php
      foreach($sizes as $key => $val){
        echo "<option value='$key'>$key - $val</option>\n";
      }
    ?>
  </select>

  <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

The output will look something like this:

```
S is equal to Small

+------------+-+
| Choose one |▼|
+------------+-+
| S - Small    |
| M - Medium   |
| L - Large    |
+--------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the array $sizes, then foreach ($sizes as $size) for your loop. THen in the echo you need this:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['list'])){
switch($size[$_REQUEST['list']])
{
  case "S":
   $size = "Small";
   break;
  case "M":
   $size = "Medium";
   break;
  case "L":
   $size = "Large";
   break;
}
    echo $size[(int)$_REQUEST['list']] . " is equal to " . " . $size . "<br />"; 

}
```

But really you would be far better using the letters as keys for the array, and the sizes as the values: $sizes['S'] = "Small" then it would be simply in your loop

```
foreach ($sizes as $key => $size)
{
echo "<option value='" . $key . "'>" . $size . "</option>";
}
```

and to display:

```
$_REQUEST['list'] . " is equal to " . " . $sizes['$_REQUEST['list']] . "<br />";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get your desired result from rewriting your code using nested arrays for your size array like:

```
$size = array();
$size[] = "";
$size[] = array("S", "Small");
$size[] = array("M", "Medium");
$size[] = array("L", "Large");
if(isset($_REQUEST['list'])){

    echo $size[(int)$_REQUEST['list']][0]." is equal to ". $size[(int)$_REQUEST['list']][1] ."<br />"; 

}

echo '<select name="list">'."\n";
$count = 0;

foreach($size as $size){
    echo '<option value="'.$count.'">'.$size[0].'</option>'."\n";

    $count++;
}
echo '</select>';
?>

<input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure I get your problem right

But why not set the value to Small, Medium & Large while you keep the output S, M, L if you want that.

Then S = Small.